# Linq - between dates query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

I am trying to convert the following sql query as a linq query, however I keep experiencing an error -

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'.

**SQL Query:**

```
select top 3 Deal, [property], [event], [Date] from [dbo]. [Database_CRE_Events] 
where (convert(datetime,[Date],103) between '01-May-2015' and '15-May-2015')  and [property] is not NULL 
order by convert(datetime,[Date],103) desc
```

I believe this is happening because `c.Date` is a string field from the entity database.  I have tried converting the date values to string and datetime to get the following to work, but I keep getting an operand error.

**LINQ Query:**

```
        DateTime dat = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
        string preWeek = dat.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        DateTime dtt = DateTime.Now;
        string today = dat.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        var data = db.Database_CRE_Events.Where(c => c.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(preWeek) && c.property != null)
                      .Select(x => new Loan() { Name = x.Deal, loan = x.property, evnt = x.Event })
                      .ToList().Take(3);
        return data;
```

Is it possible to convert the original sql query to a linq query as `c.Date` being a string parameter?

Thank you for any further assistance.

Comment: You cannot use Convert.ToDateTime or any other conversion in lambda expression

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So its not possible to translate the above sql query to linq, then? Is there a certain work around it or anything? Thanks

Comment: You should not be keeping a date in a varchar field in a database. This problem ought to be tackled at source, not as a workaround.

Comment: Keep all the variables ready before using lambda expression with a specific type. Do not do any conversion in your lamda expression.

Comment: In your example you convert a `DateTime` variable `dat` into a `string` variable `preweek` and then in the lambda expression attempt to convert it back to a `DateTime`. You can miss out those steps entirely and just keep it as a `DateTime`

Comment: You can work on strings without converting it to dates. You are using convert(datetime,[Date],103) so Date should be in the form "dd/mm/yyyy". In linq you can recreate a sorted string ("yyyymmdd") with c.Date.Substring (that is translated in TSql) so the linq query can be similar to c => c.Date.Substring(6) + c.Date.Substring(3,2) + c.Date.Substring(0,2) <= "20150131" .........

Comment: Thanks @bubi, this is really helpful. I shall give this a go.  Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're introducing strings into the mix for no reason at all. Unless you *have* to convert a `DateTime` to or from a string, don't do it.

Your query should be as simple as:

```
DateTime preWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);

var data = db.Database_CRE_Events
    .Where(c => c.Date <= preWeek && c.property != null)
    .Select(x => new Loan() { Name = x.Deal, loan = x.property, evnt = x.Event })
    .ToList()
    .Take(3);
return data;
```

If `c.Date` is actually a `string`, you should fix your database so that it *isn't* a string. It's meant to be a date, so represent it as a date! If you absolutely *have* to keep it as a string, you should at least use a sortable format, such as `yyyy-MM-dd`. At that point you could use `CompareTo` - but it's horrible :(

If the format is `dd-MMM-yyyy` (as it sounds) you could *try* performing the parse in the LINQ query, still passing in a `DateTime` but parsing each value in the database:

```
.Where(c =>
   DateTime.ParseExact(c.Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= preWeek
   && c.property != null)
```

... but I wouldn't be surprised if that fails. You may want to add a view in SQL which gives a more appropriate version of the data. Fundamentally, if you have to work with a broken schema (in this case using the wrong type *and* making a poor decision about how to format the data within that type) then you should expect pain. Pass this pain up to managers in order to prioritize changing the schema...

Notes:

- You're fetching *all* the data, and then just taking the first three elements. That's a bad idea. Switch round the calls to `ToList` and `Take` after addressing the next bullet...
- "First three elements" is only meaningful with ordering. Use `OrderBy` to specify an ordering
- You're not currently using `today`, so I removed it
- If you're only interested in a date, use `DateTime.Today`
- You should carefully consider time zones, both in your database and in your calling code. This is currently using the system default time zone - is that what you want?

Comment: thank you for your explanation Jon. Unfortunately `c.Date` is stored as a string, and I unable to change this currently.  I cannot format the `preweek` datetime, as this causes operand error because unless there is a way of formatting datetime, without converting it to string.  However, I am currently looking into `compareto` method for the above linq query.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user3070072: Even if you can't change the schema in the short term, I would escalate the need to do so in the longer term. This is simply broken. Now, what is the format of the date in the database? If it's `dd-MMM-yyyy`, that's awful...

Comment: I am sorry to inform, the `c.Date` format is actually `dd-MMM-yyyy`.  the system was originally built upon the old ruins of classic asp, hence the database formatting is quite out of date and were currently working with our DBA to update the data layer.

Comment: @user3070072: Right - in that case, I think you'll have a tough time working with it in LINQ. Either add a view on top in the database which performs appropriate parsing, or do your filtering in the client code which can parse the value. I'll add another option to my answer though.